# SAS: Assign values based on amount out of total amount

Tags: variables, percentage, population

I have a table consisting of two variables; ID and Balance. ID is an identifier of an account, and balance is the total balance of that account.

What I need is to assign a value (A or B) to each account randomly, but so that approximately 70% of the total balance is assigned to A and 30% is assigned to B.

Does anyone have any idea of how to accomplish this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!